# What does "templating languages like HTMLBars" mean? what is HTMLBars? A language?

Tags: ember.js, frontend

I never heard it before. Does "templating languages like HTMLBars" related to Ember.js?

Comment: There sure are a lot of results for "HTMLBars" on Google. The first one is even the HTMLBars repository!

Answer (score 3):

I will try to explain it.

There is the templating engine and language called [`handlebars`](http://handlebarsjs.com). The language is a superset of `(X)HTML`, so can use all HTML and some specific things in curly brackets that will be replaced by the `handlebars` templating engine. This works full on string replacement. So you compile your `handlebars` template with the `handlebars` compiler and get a Javascript function that will take an Javascript Object and produce an `HTML` string by replacing the `handlebars`parts.

[`HTMLBars`](https://github.com/tildeio/htmlbars) on the other side is a full HTML parser. Its based on the `handlebars` templating language, but is actually capable of understanding your HTML code. As far as I know it does not completely support `HTML`/`SGML` so the `HTMLBars` language is a subset of the `handlebars` language.

Because of its knowledge of the HTMLPart `HTMLBars` is capable of directly building a DOM rather then an HTML String. This is faster then injecting the string into the browsers rendering engine, and allows more features. For example since `HTMLBars` ember templates are able to updates attributes like `<img src={{myUrl}} />`. This wasn't able before, because `handlebars` didn't know if a placeholder is in a Tag or not. So until `HTMLBars` you was required to do `.

`HTMLBars` is also the base of the current ember templating engine called `Glimmer`.